# SAPUI5 change detection mechanism

Tags: javascript, sapui5, key-value-observing

Hello I am writing a research paper on change detection(between model and view) mechanisms across JavaScript frameworks - Virtual DOM, Key-Value Observation, Dirty Checking(Angular JS). I am curious what kind of change detection mechanism is behind SAPUI5 - KVO, Dirty Checking or is it somewhat similar to any of these?

Comment: How is VDOM related to _change detection between model and view_? Usually, when talking about "change detection", it's about detecting changes either in rendering or data binding. Seems like this question is about both which IMHO is a bit too broad to answer.

Comment: Request for the documentation enhancement: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/issues/17

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the rendering of ui5, I've never found any official information about it. Anyway, some time ago, I saw some explanation on github, about the rendering process of one of the core controls (sap.ui.core.HTML) so it might be interesting for you.

[Rendering of preserved content](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1162)

I hope it can help you!